# If you find some code in a tutorial but the license says "you may not upload this resource to other websites" does it mean you cannot use it?

Tags: contract-law, internet, intellectual-property

I never understood the licensing behind websites like [medialoot.com](https://medialoot.com/member/license/) . They describe how to implement code so it would seen the implicit understanding they are designed to be copied. However their license says

> FREE LICENSE
>
> If you have downloaded this file without paying for an individual item
>   or a MediaLoot subscription, you are governed by the free license. The
>   free license grants you the exclusive right to use and incorporate
>   these files in your personal or commercial projects under the
>   following conditions:
>
> ```
> All uses of these free items must contain an attribution link back to MediaLoot.com or the specific download page of this resource.
> You may use this resource or adaptations of this resource in commercial or other projects for single-application or multi-use
> ```
>
> applications, however if the application is multi-use (i.e. a
>   commercial app or theme) then the attribution must be clearly visible
>   on all pages or areas where the resource is used.
>       You MAY NOT distribute or resell this resource, or its derivatives, and you may not upload this resource to other websites.
>   All sharing of this resource must be done using a link to the
>   MediaLoot download page.

So first they say that you can use it as long as you give them credit. Then they say `you may not upload this resource to other website` so does that mean you cannot use it to build your own website?

Are licenses only applicable once the material they protect crosses the threshold to be patentable or copyrightable? For example if you took a few lines of CSS from [this page](https://medialoot.com/blog/how-to-create-a-responsive-navigation-menu-using-only-css/) would the license even apply?

Basically I'm asking is, can you use code snip-its found on websites with these kinds of "licenses"? For context I'm most curious about a single person using it for non-commercial activity.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Broadly speaking, the license allows any user of the code to use the code in any website, and use it in any way you want, so long as it is a **functional part** of the project/application/website that you are working on (so long as the user attributes the code to the original provider of the code, of course)

In my interpretation, the meaning of "you may not distribute/resell the resource" is taken to mean you may not create a web page which, in a similar way to Medialoot's page, shows people how to use that code, and how to incorporate it into their own code. Hence why I highlighted "functional" in my first paragraph. This clause seems to only ban ways people can try to resell the code or redistribute it, rather than banning people from using it **functionally** in their own projects